# style is not defined interfaces in puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

[image]

I can't use **style** in Typescript. It will cause an error like this:

```
Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element'.ts(2339)
```

So, how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

the querySelector from Element type in dom.lib in nodejs does not return the style as type.
That does not mean you cannot access it.
Try like this:

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
      const wrapperEl = document.querySelector('#wrapper');
      wrapperEl['style']['left'] = - 300 + 'px';
});
```

You can use return also from `evaluate` block to confirm that style is set or misc.

```
const result = page.evaluate(() => return something;);
```

More examples in https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.evaluate

Comment: wrapperEl['style']['left'] couldn't repress the error warning

Comment: and what is the error ?

Comment: Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element'.ts(2339)